# Adplus dump creation failed - access is denied

Tags: windbg, adplus

I'm trying to get a dump to debug some memory issues in ASP.NET processes (Windows 2003 R2 SP2 x64):

```
adplus -hang -o f:\dumps -pn w3wp.exe -quiet
```

There are nine w3wp.exe (all from different websites). Everytime I run adplus as above some of the dumps fail with this error:

```
WriteFullMemory.Memory.Read(0x100ea0000, 0x10000) failed 0x80070005, ABORT.
Dump creation failed, Win32 error 0n5
    "Access is denied."
```

The failure seems to be random (or I should say I can't find the reasons), i.e. sometimes some processes dump fine and sometimes they fail with this error. Things I checked:

- I do have full administration permissions
- There is plenty space on the target hard drive
- I disabled pinging and failure protection on IIS to prevent IIS from killing the processes while adplus is dumping.

Anything else I should check? Has anyone else run into this issue? Adplus version is 7.01.002 (02/27/2009) (downloaded a couple of days ago from the latest SDK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of inaccessible memory read failure. To avoid this you could use something like cdb/windbg and use `.dump /mA` command to generate full memory dump.

The `.dump /mA` same as `.dump /ma` except that it will ignore inaccessible memory read failure and continue minidump generation.

[.dump options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562428%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The /mA option is equivalent to /ma
>   except that it ignores any failure to
>   read inaccessable memory and continues
>   generating the minidump.

HTH

Comment: +1 Sounds good, thanks! But why would there be inaccessible memory... only sometimes? Wouldn't I get a partial (potentially useless) dump this way?

Comment: I think memory could have been paged out that's reason for inaccessible memory. No it won't give partial dump.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't matter if you are a member of admin you would still need to elevate privileges.

ADPlus needs to be run from a command prompt running under a local administrator account with elevated privileges. If you fail to do this, the dump file may not be created.